# Extruding horizantally when I want it to go vertically, and vice versa

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I'm trying to extrude a cylinder in the right direction.
But to extrude I have to move the cursor verticaly.

Same with the vertical direction.
If I wanted to extrude the cylinder in the vertical direction, say a few faces, I have to move the cursor in the horizantal direction.

[image]

Comment: by default the extrusion will follow the face normal, but you can press E to extrude, then Enter right away to validate, then move in the direction you want?

Comment: I don't see a gif, only a link with lots of numbers which leads me to a page with adds. Could you please use [the builtin tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) to [upload a gif](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers). They won't expire and the question will be easier to understand and produce better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen, when you *Extrude Along Normals*.
To have the extrusion follow you cursor, use *Extrude Region* instead.

[image]